# Using TikZ package makes PDF corrupted for Adobe Reader

Tags: tikz-pgf, pdf, adobe

Recently while creating a newsletter using PaperTeX class I wanted to use the TikZ package for inserting a background image, but after using the package the resultant PDF is not being loaded completely by Adobe Acrobat reader with error code `110`.

Then after searching for similar issues I found out that font loading was paused at 0% and this can happen sometimes when a code snippet not compatible with Adobe is added to a file. This is a security measure by Adobe which prevents users from targeted malwares.

*So I wanted know if there is some way to use the TikZ package and still be able to open the pdf with Adobe acrobat reader DC?*

**Note**: I removed all TikZ package references and kept only `usepackage{tikz}` 
and still faced same issue. Also if this is a singular occurrence due to PaperTeX  + TikZ class then please point that out. Currently I resorted to using `eso-pic` and `graphicx` packages.

Comment: There are many free and open source pdf viewers out there... Did you tried one of them? Was it corrupted too?

Comment: papertex is probably doing something that shouldn't do. TikZ is used everywhere.

Comment: I tried pdflite and and Google chrome I built viewer. It was fine. This is something that Adobe products keep as security check. Our aim is to reach a very wide audience so it should work with everything.

Comment: If I compile some `\documentclass{papertex}` document without any Ti*k*z with `xelatex`, this fails. If I use `pdflatex`, it works even with Ti*k*z pictures. Did you try using `pdflatex`?

Comment: I only tried pdflatex and issue occurred. Trying to understand the root cause here.

Comment: I guess you should add a [minimal non-working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Comment: Sometimes transparencies or shadings can cause such problems. But without a MWE it is impossible to say if this is the problem in your case.

Comment: Apologies for not providing a MWE earlier. Anyways I was able to figure out the problem. It is because of undefined opacity in tikz node. Pasting code snippet in answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the mistake. As pointed out by @samcarter it is an issue with ambiguous opacity setting. In one of the background images I had written

```
 \tikz[remember picture, overlay] 
   \node[opacity=,inner sep=0pt] at (current page.center)
    {includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{image}};
```

It should have been

```
\tikz[remember picture, overlay] 
  \node[opacity=0.5,inner sep=0pt] at(current page.center)
  {includegraphics[width=\paperwidth, height =\paperheight]{image}};
```

Not defining opacity corrupts the file for adobe reader.